# ForAllMembers overriding Ignore rules already defined

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using `AutoMapper` and I need to ignore members where an `Attribute` is not defined.  Then, if the Member is not being ignored, I need to map only where values are defined.  I have managed to achieve these two separately, but `ForAllMembers`/`ForAllOtherMembers` seems to be overriding the first rule.

Let's say I have this class:

```
public class Foo
{
    [MyCustomAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string IgnoreMe { get; set; }

    [MyCustomAttribute]
    public int? DontIgnoreNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I want to ignore `IgnoreMe` regardless.  Then, for `Name` and `DontIgnoreNumber`, I want to map them only if they have a value.  How can I achieve this?

I have tried this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Foo, Foo>()
        .IgnoreAllNonAttributedEntities()
        .ForAllOtherMembers(opts =>
        {
            opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) =>
            {
                // Check if source is a default value
                return srcMember != null;
            });
        });
});
```

I have checked that the `ForAllOtherMembers` rule is working.  And I, separately, have checked that the `IgnoreAllNonAttributedEntities` is working.  When I try to combine them, the `ForAllOtherMembers` seems to be taking priority.

`IgnoreAllNonAttributedEntities` is defined as:

```
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> IgnoreAllNonAttributedEntities<TSource, TDestination>
    (this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
{
    var flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
    //var sourceType = typeof(TSource);
    var destinationType = typeof(TDestination);

    foreach(var prop in destinationType.GetProperties(flags))
    {
        var attr = ReflectionHelpers.GetAttribute<MyCustomAttribute>(prop);
        if (attr == null)
        {
            expression.ForMember(prop.Name, opt => opt.Ignore());
        }
    }

    return expression;
}
```

Comment: "I want to map them only if they have a value.", if these properties does not have a value, it will just set null or is there any other scenario where it can be a problem?

Comment: If it's `null` or `default`, I want to *not* map, otherwise *do* map iff it has a `MyCustomAttribute` defined.  So condition for mapping == has attribute AND is not a null value.

Comment: I am confused... are Mapping `Foo` to itself? And If `DontIgnoreNumber` is Null, what should be the value in the result object? Don't forget that AutoMapper is initializing the result object, so this is important.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini Yes.  I have an instance of `Foo` and another instance of `Foo`.  Both already initialised.  Foo -> Foo.  If source `DontIgnoreNumbner` is `null`, then result `DontIgnoreNumber` should also be `null`.

Comment: Then why do you want to ignore it? Can't you just let Automapper copy the source to destination? I have not test it, but I believe if source is null, then the destination would be null too (don't think you need to ignore anything).

Comment: @HoomanBahreini My mistake and I mispoke.  My use-case is: It *must* be a decorated attribute in order to get mapped.  Source *must* be non-null in order to be mapped and make its way to the result object.

Answer (score 2):

I've just run your code and it works as expected. However, maybe what bothers you is the default value of value types in c# (cuz you only check for nulls). Here is my fix for value types:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Foo, Foo>()
        .IgnoreAllNonAttributedEntities()
        .ForAllOtherMembers(opts =>
        {
            opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) =>
            {
                var srcType = srcMember?.GetType();
                if (srcType is null)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                return (srcType.IsClass && srcMember != null)
                || (srcType.IsValueType
                && !srcMember.Equals(Activator.CreateInstance(srcType)));
            });
        });
});
```

I've recreated your scenerio using latest version of automapper available on NuGet (8.0.0.0).